savebox + userbeamerfont in beamer not working as expected
I want to create my own title page in beamer. I am attempting to position a title and subtitle in a TiKZ environment by working out the height of the title and positioning the subtitle below it, so that a multi-line title would not obscure the subtitle. My try at this was using saveboxes and grabbing the height of the content that is not printed. Then I can work out the coordinate of the subtitle by calculating the height of the box.
But, it doesn't work. It appears to grab the height of the title in "default text" mode, and then use that as the height, which is not what I want.
I am open to suggestions to make this easier, but I still don't understand why my current method shouldn't work.
I have created the following MWE below to illustrate this.

\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% Formatting
\setbeamerfont{title}{family=\sffamily,series=\mdseries,size={\fontsize{50}{60}},shape=\upshape}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{fg=red}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{family=\sffamily,series=\mdseries,size={\fontsize{30}{36}},shape=\upshape}
\setbeamercolor*{subtitle}{fg=blue}

% Change maketitle
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    % Define saveboxes
    \newsavebox{\mysaveboxTitle}
    \savebox{\mysaveboxTitle}{%
        \fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{%
            \centering\usebeamerfont*{title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\inserttitle%
        }}%
    }%
    \newsavebox{\mysaveboxSubtitle}
    \savebox{\mysaveboxSubtitle}{%
        \fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{%
            \centering\usebeamerfont*{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle%
        }}%
    }%

    % Grab height of savebox
    \newlength{\titleheight}
    \settoheight{\titleheight}{\mysaveboxTitle}
    
    % Draw title page using tikz
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \coordinate (title_position) at (current page.center);
        \coordinate (subtitle_position) at ($ (title_position) - (0,\titleheight) $);
        
        \node[anchor=north] at (title_position){\usebox{\mysaveboxTitle}};
        \node[anchor=north] at (subtitle_position){\usebox{\mysaveboxSubtitle}};
        \node[anchor=north] at (title_position){%
            \parbox{\textwidth}{%
                \centering\rule{2pt}{\titleheight} Title%
            }
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

% Set title and subtitle
\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}

% Make document with just a title page
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}

The rule + "Title" text are just to illustrate what I think it's doing.

Welcome to TeX.SX!

Instead of manually calculating coordinates, I would position the subtitle south of the title:
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Formatting
\setbeamerfont{title}{family=\sffamily,series=\mdseries,size={\fontsize{50}{60}},shape=\upshape}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{fg=red}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{family=\sffamily,series=\mdseries,size={\fontsize{30}{36}},shape=\upshape}
\setbeamercolor*{subtitle}{fg=blue}

% Change maketitle
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%    
    % Draw title page using tikz
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[anchor=north,text width=\linewidth,align=center] (title) at (current page.center){%
          \usebeamerfont{title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\inserttitle\par
        };
        \node[anchor=north,text width=\linewidth,align=center] at (title.south){%
          \usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% Set title and subtitle
\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\title{Title Title Title Title Title Title}

\maketitle
\end{document}



Some other notes:

You need to finish the paragraph before switching back to another font size. If you don't the line spacing of your title will be wrong.

Instead of overwriting the definition of \maketitle, better change the title page template. This way you retain all the normal functionality of \maketitle like being able to use it both inside and outside of frames.



I didn't think of this, but this is an elegant solution to the problem!

If you try
\ShowCommand{\mysaveboxTitle}

you'll get in the log
> \mysaveboxTitle=\char"55.

which is a T. So
\settoheight{\titleheight}{\mysaveboxTitle}

gives
\settoheight{\titleheight}{T}

which is not what you want.
You can try, alternatively,
\settoheight{\titleheight}{\usebox{\mysaveboxTitle}}

It's better, but doesn't account the box depth (if you have letters with descender like "p"). Use instead
\setlength{\titleheight}{\ht\mysaveboxTitle}
\addtolength{\titleheight}{\dp\mysaveboxTitle}

(or \settototalheight of the calc package).
Example:
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% Formatting
\setbeamerfont{title}{family=\sffamily,series=\mdseries,size={\fontsize{50}{60}},shape=\upshape}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{fg=red}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{family=\sffamily,series=\mdseries,size={\fontsize{30}{36}},shape=\upshape}
\setbeamercolor*{subtitle}{fg=blue}

% Change maketitle
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    % Define saveboxes
    \newsavebox{\mysaveboxTitle}
    \savebox{\mysaveboxTitle}{%
        \fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{%
            \centering\usebeamerfont*{title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\inserttitle%
        }}%
    }%
    \newsavebox{\mysaveboxSubtitle}
    \savebox{\mysaveboxSubtitle}{%
        \fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{%
            \centering\usebeamerfont*{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle%
        }}%
    }%

    % Grab height of savebox
    \newlength{\titleheight}
    \setlength{\titleheight}{\ht\mysaveboxTitle}
    \addtolength{\titleheight}{\dp\mysaveboxTitle}

    % Draw title page using tikz
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \coordinate (title_position) at (current page.center);
        \coordinate (subtitle_position) at ($ (title_position) - (0,\titleheight) $);

        \node[anchor=north] at (title_position){\usebox{\mysaveboxTitle}};
        \node[anchor=north] at (subtitle_position){\usebox{\mysaveboxSubtitle}};
        \node[anchor=north] at (title_position){%
            \parbox{\textwidth}{%
                \centering\rule{2pt}{\titleheight} Title%
            }
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

% Set title and subtitle
\title{Titlep}
\subtitle{Subtitle}

% Make document with just a title page
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}


Anyway, samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz's answer is much simpler.

Agreed samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz's answer is better, but this was a useful explanation for why it didn't work.
